# Update Panel is not working over there "OnSelectedIndexChanged" Event which is inside a repeater

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, updatepanel, repeater, asprepeater

I have put an update panel in a page and its working properly.In  that page i was 
loading an repeater and its also working properly.But inside that repeater i am firing an event **"OnSelectedIndexChanged"** in a dropdownList .while using it the page is getting refreshed. seems update panel is not working over there.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="update_invest" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
  <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptinvest" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptactions_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlemployee" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged"
   AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   </td>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

the above is the code....!!

Thanks Arshad..!

Comment: I am assuming that you missed closing tag of content template while copy pasting right?

Comment: Can you show your code behind?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to register the postback triggering controls inside update panel. In your code snippet, it is ddlemployee. If it was in the mark up, you can do so like:

```
<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlemployee" EventName="OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

However, drop down control is nested inside repeater that you have to register it from code behind like:

```
For Each item As RepeaterItem In rptinvest.Items

 Dim ddlemployee As DropDownList = DirectCast(item.FindControl("ddlemployee"), DropDownList)
 ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(ddlemployee)

Next
```

Hope this help you. Visit [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) for more information about update panel and triggers.

Comment: I'm not the asker, but you have perfectly helped me. There is an appending from me, the RegisterAsyncPostBackControl statement has to be added at all the places where could refresh the update panel, otherwise if the update panel refreshed, the registration will be invalid. I guess it's because the trigger is bound at javascript side, the update panel refresh will start all the javascript binding from new.

Comment: Another interesting clue is that if X-UA-Compatible is set to IE=8, no need to register anything, the drop down list within the update panel will be partially refreshed automatically by drop down list children.